# GPIO and Python - GPIO.output() not working

Tags: gpio, python

I want to program a simple thermostat, but for some reason the commands GPIO.output(21, 1) or GPIO.output(21, 0) do not change anything.

In a similar vein, GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT, initial=0) does indeed setup the pin for output, but it's automatically on, despite the initial=0...

Here's the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
ventein = GPIO.output(20, 1)
ventaus = GPIO.output(20, 0)
```

calling ventein or ventaus further down the line does not do anything. The pin is just always on. I suspected that maybe it has something to do with user permissions, so I added both root and the user to the gpio group - didn't do anything.

Toggling the pin with the gpio command line tool works just fine. What could be the problem?

And here's the complete code, just in case:

```
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
ventein = GPIO.output(20, 1)
ventaus = GPIO.output(20, 0)

muro = W1ThermSensor(W1ThermSensor.THERM_SENSOR_DS18B20, "011445ff9daa")
murotemp = muro.get_temperature()

try:
    while True:
        if murotemp > 20:
            ventein
            print(murotemp)
            print("Temperatur ist hoeher als 20 Grad, schalte ein...")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            muro = W1ThermSensor(W1ThermSensor.THERM_SENSOR_DS18B20, "011445ff9daa")
            murotemp = muro.get_temperature()

        elif murotemp < 20:
            ventaus
            print(murotemp)
            print("Temperatur ist niedriger als 20 Grad, schalte aus...")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            muro = W1ThermSensor(W1ThermSensor.THERM_SENSOR_DS18B20, "011445ff9daa")
            murotemp = muro.get_temperature()


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print("exiting...")
```

Comment: First, you do nothing when `murotemp == 20` it's normal ?

Comment: Yes, probably I should make it "if murotemp => 20: "

Comment: And, `ventein = GPIO.output(20, 1)
ventaus = GPIO.output(20, 0)` are not in the loop in a conditionnal scope or other... then you init the same GPIO number at HIGH and then at LOW state for the global scope. That it's a logic problem because you use the same pin for `ventein` and `ventaus`

Comment: Yes if you want to check at `20 Grad`

Comment: ok, now that I removed the global ```ventein = GPIO.output(20, 1) ventaus = GPIO.output(20, 0)``` it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace ventein with GPIO.output(20, 1) and ventaus with GPIO.output(20, 0).

You seem to think you have declared them as functions - you have not.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. (you are probably rightly suspecting it, I'm a bloody beginner, haha.)

Comment: I hope you will be pleased to know this is a common mistake and one which I think is quite logical to make.  It's like assigning a macro in other languages.

Answer (score 6):

As joan's answer has already pointed out the misunderstanding here is likely how to define and use a function in Python. Joan's approach will sure solve the immediate problem and make the program work. I will however address the underlying issue that is not so much related to the Pi but general Python programming.

So how to go about defining and using a function, from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions):

> - Function blocks begin with the keyword **def** followed by the function name and parentheses ( ( ) ).
> - Any input parameters or arguments should be placed within these parentheses. You can also define parameters inside these parentheses.
> - The first statement of a function can be an optional statement - the documentation string of the function or docstring.
> - The code block within every function starts with a colon (:) and is indented.
> - The statement return [expression] exits a function, optionally passing back an expression to the caller. A return statement with no arguments is the same as return None.

So instead of

```
ventein = GPIO.output(20, 1)
```

this is what you're looking for:

```
def ventein():
    GPIO.output(20, 1)
```

Note the `def` keyword, the function name (ventein), the parentheses (empty in this case as no arguments are required), and the colon. The final `return` is ommitted in this case as it is optional if you do not want to pass anything back to the caller.

And when calling this new function instead of:

```
try:
    while True:
        if murotemp > 20:
            ventein
```

it should read:

```
try:
    while True:
        if murotemp > 20:
            ventein()
```